# Search engine over text corpus

Tags: search, search-engine

I have a couple of text file and I try to find the easiest way to drop all the files into one place and create a basic search query (with flexibility for little changes, search operators, etc.) over the corpus. Is there any made tool that allows that?

I'm using windows 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Windows built-in Search indexing, I find free [DocFetcher](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) a very powerful indexed search tool. As you set it up, you define the folders (and all subfolders) to index and to be watched by *docfetcher-daemon-windows.exe*, which indexes new files dropped into those folders.

*DocFetcher* has a simple query syntax, can index a *huge* variety of file formats, in addition to plain text, and indexes are rapidly created.

The only disadvantage is that it requires Java to be installed. However, relying on Java enables this application to run on many platforms, including Linux, as well as on Windows. For example, in the image below, I selected to index everything in the Windows Documents folder, as well as other locations.

[image: DocFetcher GUI]